# How I hide a div when jquery show another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that when the click activate the element2 div, the element should disappear. And the element2 div should not appear at the beginning.

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(".element2").toggle();
});


$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".element2").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  Element 1
  <div class="toggle">
    toggle
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    Element 2 
    <div class="close">close Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made two different file. The jquery's file linked to the html.

Comment: @Ramesh What ajax code are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have element2 hidden at the beginning you need to either add a style tag or even better add a CSS file where you will keep all of your stylings in one place.

For style tag:

```
<div class="element2" style="display:none">
```

For CSS:

```
.element2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Then for your code you are close. In order to make element hide, you need to change it to:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".element2").show();
    $(".element").hide();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
    $(".element2").hide();
    $(".element").show();
});
```

The HTML will need some changes to, this will make what I wrote work the way I believe you want it to:

```
<div class="element">
  Element 1
  <div class="toggle">
    toggle
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  Element 2 
  <div class="close">close Element 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this code, the element div disappear before it appear the element2

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't see your element2 div was contained in the element div.  Unless you pull the element2 div outside of the element div then you can't hide element while showing element2

Comment: Oh shit! Thanks! I had not really seen it! But if i put the div2 outside, how I place it on the div element?

Comment: I updated the HTML, if you want to appearance to change then you'll want to accomplish that with CSS.  Most people who aren't design experts (and some who are) use bootstrap to help with the layout of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Add display none to hide an element from the start:

```
<div class="element2" style="display:none">
```

The rest of your code appears to be doing what it's supposed to, unless I am misunderstanding "I want that when the click activate the element2 div, the element should disappear"... which is entirely possible.

Comment: My problem is that the div in background, element, doesn't disappear. And i don't know why!

Comment: @Davikx Check out my answer, I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

just `$(".element2").hide();` hide it at start

```js
$(function() {
  $(".element2").hide();
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".element2").toggle();
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".element2").hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">Element 1
  <div class="toggle">Toggle </div>
  <div class="element2"> Element 2
    <div class="close"> close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing it this way will cause a flicker.  The initial hide must be in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like this:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".element2").toggle();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide(); // close the correct .element2
});
```

In CSS you need to:

```
.element2 {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Then he has to change his code if he changes his HTML

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
   <div class="element">
      <div class="toggle"></div>
      <div class="element2" style="display:none">
        <div class="close"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**EXAMPLE CSS**

```
.toggle
{
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
  float:left;
  background:green;
}

.element2{
  display:block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:10px;
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
}
.close{
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(".element2").toggle();
});


$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".element2").css({"display":"none"});
});
```

[fiddle to check](https://jsfiddle.net/52bwa4hg/13/)

**I hope it is helpfull answer. Good Luck !**